# Symfony AJAX response doesn't return whole data?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a simple logic which get All comments, then I get all subcomments for each comment and return this to Javascript (via AJAX), but it does not return whole response.

Controller:

```
$comments = $commentRepo->getPaginationPost(1, 0, $id);

foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
    $subcomments = $commentRepo->getSubComments($comment->getId());
    $comment->subComments = $subcomments;
}

$response = [
    'comments' => $comments,
    'id' => $id,
    'totalPages' => $totalPages
];

return new JsonResponse($response);
```

If I `dump($reponse); exit;`, before return it looks like this:

```
ArticleController.php on line 194:
array:3 [
  "comments" => array:1 [
    0 => & Comment {#7263
      -id: 168
      -content: "Лошо е"
      -person: User {#5420
        #id: 3
        -firstName: "testtt"
        -favouriteArticles: PersistentCollection {#5653
          -snapshot: []
          -owner: User {#5420}
          -association: array:19 [ …19]
          -em: EntityManager {#3456 …11}
          -backRefFieldName: null
          -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#5424 …}
          -isDirty: false
          #collection: ArrayCollection {#5688
            -elements: []
          }
          #initialized: true
        }
        #username: "test@test.com"
        #usernameCanonical: "test@test.com"
        #email: "test@test.com"
        #emailCanonical: "test@test.com"
        #enabled: true
        #salt: null
        #password: "$2y$13$.8Ky5Jj71PUsGD9E04nre./xClPVZ/Uiia40PTQjGmMAqOFpW2mwi"
        #plainPassword: null
        #lastLogin: DateTime {#5416
          +"date": "2019-01-07 09:39:06.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "UTC"
        }
        #confirmationToken: null
        #passwordRequestedAt: null
        #groups: null
        #roles: []
      }
      -dateAdded: DateTime {#7260
        +"date": "2019-01-09 11:02:35.000000"
        +"timezone_type": 3
        +"timezone": "UTC"
      }
      -replyTo: 0
      -postId: 8
      +"subComments": []
    }
  ]
  "id" => "8"
  "totalPages" => 2.0
]
```

But In JS if I `console.log` of returned data is:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogklg.png)

Only subcomments are there and I cannot access content of comment.

Comment: If I remove whole `foreach` and just return comments it is  the same - empty objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not convert object to JSON automatically here. 
So you need to prepare data for JSON as simple array which can convert to JSON. Also, It's bad idea to use requests to database inside foreach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your properties are `protected` and `private`, as denoted by the `#` and `-` signs.

The `protected` and `private` properties will not appear in your response so you would need to set the values manually using getter methods or make your properties public.

Comment: To set all properties to public is not good, can you provide more information about "need to set the values manually using getter methods"

Comment: @ФилипНедялков I agree about the visibility. You could use getters to set the values manually like `'comments' => ['id => $comment->getId(), ...]` but personally I would probably provide a method in the `Comment` class that returns an array of all the properties you want to set in the response.